# Running a python program from a hotkey in kubuntu 22.04?

Tags: python, ubuntu, executable

I have a python program that can be executed by navigating to the folder it is located in using cd, and using the

`python3 main.py`

command. Is there any way I can assign a hotkey to run this program, or at least open console, navigate to that folder, and execute the program?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the top of the terminal you can see a button to add the shortcut. After that add the file path as command then set the shortcut

Comment: nvm got it to work, I had to add /bin/python3 to the beginning